# Wireless (Wi-fi) in HP 11 F 105 is not working

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, broadcom

I have a netbook HP 11 F105 which is bundling with Win 10,
But i want to use Ubuntu 14.04, just single boot, and it works.

Now, th problem is, the wi-fi is not running,
I use this command : `sudo lshw -C network > wireless.txt`

It gives me

```
*-network
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:90500000-90507fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 07
       serial: 98:e7:f4:4c:14:b0
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=10.60.36.231 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:263 ioport:1000(size=256) memory:90404000-90404fff memory:90400000-90403fff memory:90c00000-90c0ffff
```

I see, the broadcom it exist, but, wi-fi still not runninig.
Any help it so appreciated.